# Adding two numbers in char variables read with scanf

Tags: c

I was teaching the C programming language to a friend and we came up with something I could not explain. This is the code we wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char num1;
    char num2;

    printf("%s", "Enter the first number: ");   
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("%s%d\n", "The number entered is:", num1);

    printf("%s", "Enter the second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("%s%d\n", "The number entered is:", num2);

    printf("%s%d\n", "The first number entered was:", num1); /* This was done for testing */
    printf("%s%d\n", "The sum is:", num1+num2);

    return 0;
}
```

The weird thing is that we tried to do 5 + 6 and we expected to get 11 but instead got 6, I added a line to see what's going on with the first number and it becomes 0 after the second number is read.

I am aware that the variables should be an `int` (in fact the original code was like that and worked) but my understanding is that a `char` is a small integer so I thought it would be 'safe' to use if we were adding small numbers.

The code was tested and compiled on a Linux machine with `cc` and on a Windows machine with `cl`. The output was the same. On the Windows machine the program throw an error after the addition.

I would like an explanation on why this code is not working as I expected. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Use `scanf("%hhd", &num1);`

Comment: You can also included text in the format of `printf`. E.g. `printf ("The number entered is: %d\n", num2);` That prevents having to specify `%s` for the static text itself. (assuming you corrected the input issues per-below)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I was skimming the pages on some Tannenbaum book and I remember reading that doing it could lead to a security issue.

Comment: Hmm, I think you have it backwards. There is no possibility of injecting anything into the **literal** part of the format string (i.e. printf ("whatever you want = %d\n", yourint). There is no way anybody can change `whatever you want`. I think you are referring to examples given related to [**Uncontrolled format string**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string). Where the example **bad:** `printf(buffer);` is compared to **good:** `printf("%s", buffer);` If this is what you are thinking, it is a misinterpretation of the example. (notice no quotes in **bad**)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: You are right, I haven't read that far into the book yet. As an experiment, I replaced a literal inside an .exe file with a text editor like this `wh%sev%s y%s want` and it just replaced the characters at the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **cannot** pass a pointer to a different datatype to `scanf`. `scanf` will write to memory assuming you gave it a pointer to what it expected (e.g. `int` for `%d`), and will exhibit wonderful undefined behaviour if you give it a pointer to a different datatype.

Here, what is most likely happening is that `scanf` is overwriting e.g. 4 bytes on your stack when your `char`s only take up 1 byte, so `scanf` will just be happily writing right over some other variable on your stack.

Comment: So that explains why the value is changed to 0 when the second number is read. Thanks for the enlightenment!

Comment: @Gerardo: Note that the explanation is basically a guess. The behaviour is fundamentally undefined; I'm guessing based on what I'd expect a compiler might do. (Don't rely on this kind of behaviour, of course!)

Answer (score 3):

> a char is a small integer so I thought it would be 'safe' to use it if we were adding small numbers.

That is correct, `char` is a small integral type , and it's OK to use it in integer arithmetic(although `char` may be signed or unsigned which may causes the result unexpected).

But the problem is, **a pointer to `char`** can NOT be used in a place where **a pointer to `int`** is expected. And this is the case for `scanf("%d", &num1);`, the second parameter is expected to a of type `int *`.